# SQL Query Parent Child Recursive

Tags: mysql, sql

in a mySQL database i have several tables structured like this:

```
TABLEA: | ID | PARENT | FOO |
TABLEB: | ID | PARENT | BAR |
TABLEC: | ID | PARENT | MOO |
```

PARENT is the ID of a record in any of the other tables - EDIT: I will know the first table of the top level node in advance.

I need to query the database starting with a one ID that would be the top level of a tree with any possible depth so if I was to search for the children of the first node of the tree:

```
select * from TABLEA where PARENT = "1234"
select * from TABLEB where PARENT = "1234"
select * from TABLEC where PARENT = "1234"
```

and combine the results, then iterate through the results and run the query again using the ID of the first nodes children to get each child nodes for the second level, then repeat this for each child until i've found all child nodes for each parent at which point i have my tree.

This is very slow and requires many calls to the database.  I'm looking for a SQL trick that let's me build this dataset in one go.  The top level node could be from any table.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this something that can be converted to an actual hierarchy model, e.g. [adjacency list](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)?

Comment: @SqlZim sadly, i'm trying to fix a performance issue on a legacy system and changing the table / model structure isn't an option.

Comment: @bsautner . . . Perhaps you should be more open.  You can run a job once to structure the data with the full path for each item, and then keep it up to date with triggers.  This might be the best overall solution for your problem.  "MySQL" and "recursive" just don't go together.